Custom list view button not clickable no action on community
I have create a custom list view button on Asset object to perform update action on status of selected records.
This list view button is triggering flow and performing the action. I have done this and checked this with internal user in lightning experience and it seems to be working fine. But for my community user, buttons are visible on list view, yet they are not clickable or any action happens when i try to click on them.
I have even put the debug logs on user, but it is not triggering the flow at all.
About permissiosn,
OWD for asset for community is public read/write.
Permission set which is assigned to community user is having 'run flow' access as well, flow access and object level access is also read/edit.
For profile, it's standard profile, i.e. Partner community user which is not editable for user. That's why using permission set.
I have tried debugging the flow but as it is receiving multiple recordIds, it's not receiving input param of recordId that's why can't trust those logs.
Can anyone help me out, what else could be missing here to have my flow not getting triggered from List view button on community.
Again, it's working fine from internal user.

Welcome to SFSE.  It seems like you have checked all the possible aspects, I recommend opening a case with Salesforce.

Thanks for the warm welcome, I will do the suggested.

Good luck!  When you open your case, be sure to include a debug log file  to show them that the flow is not executing.

Hey @DavidCheng, I tried raising the case, but I ended up creating a trailhead community post. Could you guide me where I could find the option to raise the case with Salesforce, so they can confirm on this feature.

To all, so there's no answer to this. It's a limitation by salesforce. I am mentioning the link to stop all of your research and stop banging your head like me.
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmeRUAR/url-button-support-in-lightning-community

In Salesforce, click the question mark icon at top right and choose Get Support

You can post your own answer and accept it.
